# Push data from Excel to Db2

Tags: database, vba, excel, db2

I am very new to Db2 and also VBA to an extent. Could somebody help me out with below request.

I request somebody to help me with a sample code.... Say I have a table in db2...

Name and Employee Id

Now I have the details in Excel.... Say in sheet1.. Column A is Name and Column B is Emp ID

I require a code with which I can make a connection to my database and push the data to my tables in db2....(Probably with some explanation like code breakdown @ important palces)

Please help me with this request.. Thousand thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before without any code using a simple process:

1. Create a new database in Microsoft Access.
2. Import the Excel spreadsheet into a new table in the new Access database.
3. Set up an ODBC datasource that points to the DB2 database you want to import into.
4. Use the ODBC connection from Access to export the table into DB2.

Comment: I could use this if I will be the only person using it... but the excel I create will be distributed across my team and everybody will be using it... i.e. by connecting to our DB server... It wouldn't be good to ask users to follow these steps because my Primary goal of simplifying the task itself is not met by this way ...